# Prefetch in cuda (through C code)

Tags: cuda, prefetch

I am working on data prefetch in CUDA (Fermi GPU) through C code. Cuda reference manual talks about the prefetching at ptx level code  not at C level code.

Can anyone connect me with some documents or something regarding prefetching through cuda code (cu file). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

According to [PTX manual](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/ptx_isa_3.0.pdf) here is how prefetch works in PTX:

[image]

You can embed the PTX instructions into the CUDA kernel. Here is a tiny sample from [NVIDIA's documentation](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/Using_Inline_PTX_Assembly_In_CUDA.pdf):

```
__device__ int cube (int x)
{
  int y;
  asm("{\n\t"                       // use braces for local scope
      " .reg .u32 t1;\n\t"           // temp reg t1,
      " mul.lo.u32 t1, %1, %1;\n\t" // t1 = x * x
      " mul.lo.u32 %0, t1, %1;\n\t" // y = t1 * x
      "}"
      : "=r"(y) : "r" (x));
  return y;
}
```

You may come to conclude with the following prefetch function in C:

```
__device__ void prefetch_l1 (unsigned int addr)
{

  asm(" prefetch.global.L1 [ %1 ];": "=r"(addr) : "r"(addr));
}
```

NOTICE: You need the GPU of Compute Capability 2.0 or higher for prefetch. Pass proper compile flags accordingly `-arch=sm_20`

Comment: can you provide me on some more documentation on how prefetching works, like the explanation of the concept itself.

Comment: sure! check this GPGPU prefetching study and go through references to figure out more about the concept: http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~hyesoon/lee_taco12.pdf

Answer (score 3):

According to [this thread](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/913519/cuda-programming-and-performance/tuning-a-kernel-with-ldg-on-off-array-and-prefetching/), below is the code for different cache prefetching techniques:

```
#define DEVICE_STATIC_INTRINSIC_QUALIFIERS  static __device__ __forceinline__

#if (defined(_MSC_VER) && defined(_WIN64)) || defined(__LP64__)
#define PXL_GLOBAL_PTR   "l"
#else
#define PXL_GLOBAL_PTR   "r"
#endif

DEVICE_STATIC_INTRINSIC_QUALIFIERS void __prefetch_global_l1(const void* const ptr)
{
  asm("prefetch.global.L1 [%0];" : : PXL_GLOBAL_PTR(ptr));
}

DEVICE_STATIC_INTRINSIC_QUALIFIERS void __prefetch_global_uniform(const void* const ptr)
{
  asm("prefetchu.L1 [%0];" : : PXL_GLOBAL_PTR(ptr));
}

DEVICE_STATIC_INTRINSIC_QUALIFIERS void __prefetch_global_l2(const void* const ptr)
{
  asm("prefetch.global.L2 [%0];" : : PXL_GLOBAL_PTR(ptr));
}
```

Comment: Good lifting. Now we just need an example where these actually provide a benefit.

Comment: @tera I have a general rule of thumb: if Nisght Compute lists long scoreboard stalls as the top stall contributer, you're mostly going to benefit from prefetches. This rule of thumb has worked in 9/10 cases for me. It's very important for low occupancy kernels (like when you are limited to a warp or a block).