# I want to prefetch in cuda But Error occur

Tags: cuda

I am a new comer to cuda. And I want to add prefetch to cuda.

I add this to code.

```
_device_ void a(...)..{
   ....
   double value;
   ...
   asm("prefetch.global.L2 [&value];");
...}
```

but, I get this error.

```
ptxas /tmp/tmpxft_00000259_00000000-6_Simulation.ptx, line 279; fatal   : Parsing error near '&': syntax error
ptxas <macro util>, line 12; error   : Illegal modifier '.L2' for instruction 'mov'
ptxas <macro util>, line 12; error   : Illegal modifier '.L2' for instruction 'mov'
ptxas fatal   : Ptx assembly aborted due to errors
```

Can anybody help me T^T

Answer (score 2):

First of all this:

```
double value;
```

is not in the *global* space in the GPU.  It is in the logical *local* space.  You can find info about logical spaces in the [PTX documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html)

Next, when using PTX instructions, you are generally working with *registers*.  You should probably also familiarize yourself with the [inline PTX](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/inline-ptx-assembly/index.html#constraints) documentation.

This seems to compile for me:

```
#include <cstdio>
__device__ void a(){
   double value = 1.0;
   asm("prefetch.local.L2 [%0];" :: "l"(&value));
   printf("%f\n", value);
}
```

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13265993/prefetch-in-cuda-through-c-code)  may also be of interest.

Comment: Learned a lot! thx